# Sphinx PDO multiple variables in execute error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sphinx

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound
>   variables does not match number of tokens

When I try to execute the below PDO query with multiple variables I get the above error.

```
$array = $sphinx->prepare("select * from `indexname` where MATCH ('@name (:search)') AND
`price` BETWEEN :min AND :max");
$array->execute(array(':search' => $search, ':min' => $min, ':max' => $max));
```

If I just use the `:search` and change `:min and :max` to `$min and $max` the query works.

```
$array = $sphinx->prepare("select * from `indexname` where MATCH ('@name (:search)') AND `price` BETWEEN $min AND $max");
$array->execute(array(':search' => $search));
```

Can I only use 1 variable in execute with sphinx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a placeholder you can bind **[a complete data literal only](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#bindable)**.

Therefore you have to compile your search pattern in PHP first, and then send it to the query:

```
$stmt = $sphinx->prepare("select * from `indexname` where MATCH (:search) AND
`price` BETWEEN :min AND :max");
$stmt->bindValue(':search', "@name ($search)");
$stmt->bindValue(':min', (int)$min, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':max', (int)$max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: different error - 1064 sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_STRING, expecting CONST_INT (or 3 other tokens) near ''0' AND '1000'....